# Как получить массив категорий и подкатегорий упорядоченный?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Получаю список всех категорий подкатегорий в разнобой, мне как-то надо их упорядочить.
Мог бы я задать parent 0, а потом как-то их подтягивать подкатегории?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод:

```
<?php
  $args = array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat');
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
?>
                
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
  <div><?= $category->name ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Достаточно почитать документацию по используемой функции https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_categories. Но тебе лучше использовать wp_list_categories().

Comment: А и да! https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `wp_list_categories()`- вывод категорий в виде списка. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_categories) и [здесь](https://misha.agency/wordpress/wp_list_categories.html). Там же наглядные примеры.

Comment: Если даёшь ответ, то стоит приводить нужный код. Иначе это не решение, а просто попутный совет.

Comment: @SeVlad, так я привёл нужный код - `wp_list_categories()`: вызываешь эту функцию и получаешь упорядоченный древовидный список категорий и подкатегорий. Дальше стилями можно подправить внешний вид. В базовом варианте больше ничего и не надо - полноценный ответ на вопрос автора.

Comment: Нет, ты лишь указал нужную функцию. А необходимый код - это как её использовать для задачи ТСа. Т.е. нужно написать аргументы массива и тд.

Comment: @SeVlad, для базового решения задачи никаких аргументов массива не требуется - учи мат.часть. Всё аргументы массива - это дополнительные возможности данной функции.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Ты не агрись на добрые советы, а сам учи мастчать. По дефолту сортировка по имени. Что в wp_list_categories то get_categories. ТС получит тоже самое, что и на скрине в вопросе. Т.е.  решения проблемы ТСа нет.

Comment: @SeVlad, причём тут сортировка? Автор спрашивает, как получить иерархически упорядоченный список категорий и подкатегорий. Функция `wp_list_categories()` по дефолту с этим справляется. И результат будет не такой, как на скрине, а в виде древовидного списка. А сортировку уже можно добавить потом, если будет такая необходимость. Ты в сути вопроса разберись сперва, а потом лезь со своими "добрыми" советами.

Comment: Да бис для нервных:  обе функции работают одинаково. Но дело твоё. (Исправил бы - я бы плюсанул, а так..)

Comment: @SeVlad, да где ж они одинаково работают? :)) get_categories по дефолту берёт всё подряд (категории, подкатегории любого уровня) и выводит их без привязки друг к другу, просто в алфавитном порядке (как на скрине у автора). А wp_list_categories() сразу делает иерархически упорядоченный список, где видно, что есть категории, что есть подкатегории и, главное, какие подкатегории к каким категориям относятся. Что здесь одинакового? =) Это принципиально разный результат работы функций.

Comment: матчасть: wp_list_categories() - работает на основе: get_categories() А разница лишь в том что первая сразу выводит, а вторая возвращает массив

Comment: @SeVlad, и? "Одна функция работает на основе другой" и "Обе функции работают одинаково" - это не одно и то же. Ты уж определись :))

Comment: Не одно и тоже - это [пути к картинкам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1354296/233741). А ты даже [wp_query не осиливаешь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1429725/233741), но агришься и не думаешь. За сим откланиваюсь

Comment: @SeVlad, просто признай, что в данном конкретном вопросе ты облажался. И в следующий раз внимательней изучи проблему, прежде чем лезть со своими комментариями.